# Having difficulties sending data from ajax to spring mvc controller

Tags: ajax, spring, model-view-controller

My ajax code looks like this:

```
function GetProjectlist() { 
            alert(department);
            var obj = { department : department};
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url:  "http://localhost:8080/MyApplication/getAllProjects",               
                data: JSON.stringify(obj),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",         
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnGetProjectSuccess,
              error: OnGetProjectError
            });
           }
```

On the other hand my Controller looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getAllProjects", method = RequestMethod.POST,headers = {"Content-type=application/json"}) 
    public @ResponseBody JsonJtableProjectListResponse getAllProjects(@RequestParam(value = "department", required = false) String department) {        

        System.out.print("department"+department);
        logger.info("Home Controller -getAllProjects");
```

..................................................

When I print department in the controller it is null. Can anyone tell me how I can pass department from ajax to controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using @RequestBody annotation instead of @RequestParam annotation since you are sending json data. Check this article about how to do it.

> http://hmkcode.com/spring-mvc-json-json-to-java/

For simple param passing, use something like below and use @RequestParam on server side like you had earlier.

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url:  "http://localhost:8080/MyApplication/getAllProjects",               
                data: {department:department},
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnGetProjectSuccess,
              error: OnGetProjectError
            });
```

Comment: @RequestBody is working fine, and I had to create a java object to receive the value. I was wondering if this is the only way to send data from ajax to spring controller? I mean if it is possible to send a single data(not an object) from ajax to spring controller. Anyhow, thank you for your help. However, answer of my following question would be much appreciated. ( P.s. In my first ajax code, the type is actually post)

Comment: That is if you are following json route. If its just single data that you want to pass, you can simply pass them in you can simply set them as data: { name: "John"} in your get method and don't specify any contentType. Then you can simply use @RequestParam on server side. If my answer helped you, please accept them as an answer.

Comment: I added simple implementation as well.

Comment: Perfect!! Both of your answers helped me a lot. Thank you so much